# How to Make Azure Websites Have their Own Quotas

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a couple unrelated websites that I host using the free subscription of Microsoft Azure. They are currently all under the same Resource Group and same App Service plan (though I don't understand those concepts well enough to know if they should or shouldn't be).

In the past, I've had a problem with individual apps eating up large amounts of some resource, like CPU Time or Data Out. The issue is that they all share one quota... so if Website A has a problem that consumes all the CPU Time for the day, then Website A, Website B, and Website C ALL go down until the quota resets, even though Website B and Website C aren't contributing to the problem.

In short, how do I prevent that so that each website has its own quota (not a shared quota)? Can I separate the websites into different Resource Groups? Different App Service plans? I tried to understand Microsoft's documentation on how these quotas work, but I was unable to find the answer to my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a couple unrelated websites that I host using the free subscription of Microsoft Azure. They are currently all under the same Resource Group and same App Service plan (though I don't understand those concepts well enough to know if they should or shouldn't be).

Resource groups define a way to group multiple related azure resources together. Typically all resources in the same resource group are deployed together, for example using ARM/Bicep templates.

An App Service plan defines a set of compute resources for web apps to run.The free tier provides 60 minutes of cpu time per day. You can host multiple web apps on the same plan, as you do. But in that case they all consume parts of that 60 minute cpu time quota.

> In short, how do I prevent that so that each website has its own quota (not a shared quota)? Can I separate the websites into different Resource Groups? Different App Service plans? I tried to understand Microsoft's documentation on how these quotas work, but I was unable to find the answer to my question.

If you do not want to share the cpu time between the multiple web apps on the same app service plan you can create a free tier App Service Plan per web app, and deploy each web app to their own dedicated free tier App Service Plan.